# Save integers from string to vector

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdstring

I need to save integers from string to vector.

Definition of number: each of strings substrings which consists entirely of digits, with a space before the first character of that substring and a space or punctuation mark after the last character, unless the substring is at the very beginning or end of the string (in this case there does not have to be a space in front or space or punctuation behind).

`EXAMPLE 1: "120 brave students, 35 failed, remaining 85..." Numbers: 120, 35, 85`

`EXAMPLE 2: "2PAC and U2 have class" Numbers: // there aren't any numbers`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
int CharToInt(int c) {
  return abs('0' - c);
}
int MakeNumber(std::vector < int > temp) {
  int num;
  if (temp.size() == 1)
    num = temp[0];
  if (temp.size() == 2)
    num = temp[0] * 10 + temp[1];
  if (temp.size() == 3)
    num = temp[0] * 100 + temp[1] * 10 + temp[2];
  if (temp.size() == 4)
    num = temp[0] * 1000 + temp[1] * 100 + temp[2] * 10 + temp[3];
  return num;
}

std::vector < int > ExtractNumbers(std::string str) {
  std::vector < int > a;
  bool found_number;
  std::vector < int > temp;
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    // skip spaces
    found_number = false;
    while (str[i] == ' ' && i < str.length())
      i++;
    // inside word
    while (str[i] != ' ' && i < str.length()) {
      while (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9' && i < str.length()) {
        temp.push_back(CharToInt(str[i]));
        i++;
        found_number = true;
      }
      i++;
    }
    if (found_number)
      a.push_back(MakeNumber(temp));
    temp.clear();
  }
  return a;
}

int main() {
  std::vector < int > a = ExtractNumbers("120 brave students, 35 failed, remaining 85...");
  std::vector < int > b = ExtractNumbers("2PAC and U2 have class");
  for (int i: a) std::cout << i << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  for (int i: b) std::cout << i << " ";
  return 0;
}
```

> OUTPUT:
>
> 120 35 85 // ✅
>
> 2 2 // ❌

Could you help me to modify this to work correctly for the example 2?
How could I check if there is space before and space/punctuation after the number is found?

Comment: Well, if you already have a number, and you want to "append" a digit to it, can you think of an elementary formula that does it? Why, you multiply it by ten, then add the digit to it, does that make sense to you? That's basic math. So, that's exactly what you do here, just take each digit, one digit at a time, and produce a single number! Mission accomplished.

Comment: or store the digits in a string (treat it like a vector of characters) and then convert that string to an integer - use std::stoi

Comment: thank you very much, I edited my code. Could you help me to modify my code to work for example 2?

Comment: you coud use c++ `std::regex` to test if and extract the digits of a word in the string. `(\d\d*)[\.\,\;\!\?]*` is the regular expression.

Comment: @BitTickler could you post any code as example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
std::vector < int > extract_numbers(std::string s) {
  std::vector < int > vek;
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    std::string word;
    while (s[i] == ' ' && i < s.length()) i++;
    while (s[i] != ' ' && i < s.length()) word += s[i++];
    int j = 0;
    while (word[j] >= '0' && word[j] <= '9') j++;
    std::string spaces = ".,;!?";
    for (int i = 0; i < spaces.size(); i++)
      if (word[j] == spaces[i] || word[j] == '\0') {
        vek.push_back(std::stoi(word));
        break;
      }
  }
  return vek;
}
int main() {
  std::string s;
  std::getline(std::cin, s);
  for (int i: extract_numbers(s))
    std::cout << i << " ";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you can use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find instead of you for loop.

Comment: you can use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit inside your while loop where you look for digits.

Answer (score 1):

That makeNumber should be

```
int MakeNumber(std::vector <int> temp) {
    int num = 0;
    for( int digit : temp){
        num *= 10;
        num += digit;
    }
    return num;
}
```

doesnt change the answer but will work with any number of digits (assuming it fits in an int)

Comment: thank you very much, do you have any idea for the example 2? how to solve it?

Comment: @RocketProcd yes -  once you exit that inner loop with 'found_number' true, you need to look at the char you just read, make sure its a whitespace, if not then ignore the number you found

Comment: is there any way to make this condition smaller `if(str[i]!=' '&&str[i]!='.'&&str[i]!='!'&&str[i]!='?')` ? could str[i] be compared to array of characters?

Comment: I posted an answer by myself, what do you think about it?

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement, that digits may be trailed by punctuation, but not by other characters, so they are considered a number, makes the problem a little bit harder.

One way to tackle this "parsing rule" is to use regular expressions.
First, we split the input string into words (surrounded by whitespace), then
we test if the number requirement is fulfilled for a word.

Instead of falling back to nitty gritty C-style character based parsing code, we use `std::istringstream` to read one word at a time from the string.

Finally, whatever we consider a number, we convert with `std::stoi()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
#include <regex>

using StringVector = std::vector<std::string>;
using I32Vector = std::vector<int32_t>;

static std::regex number_regex(R"(\d+[\.\,\:\;\!\?]*)");

inline bool is_number(const std::string& s) {
  std::cmatch m;
  return std::regex_match(s.c_str(),m,number_regex);
}

I32Vector extract_numbers(const std::string& s) {
  I32Vector result;
  std::string word;
  std::istringstream is{s};
  while (!is.eof()) {
    is >> word;
    std::cout << "[" << word << "]";
    if (is_number(word)) {
      std::cout << " is a number.";
      std::cout.flush();
      result.push_back(std::stoi(word));
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  return result;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream,
             const I32Vector& v) {
  if (v.empty())
    stream << "()" << std::endl;
  else {
    stream << "(" << v[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < v.size(); i++) {
      stream << " " << v[i];
    }
    stream << ")" << std::endl;
  }
  return stream;
}

int main (int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  StringVector test_strings{
    "120 brave students, 35 failed, remaining 85...",
    "2PAC and U2 have class",
    "120 brave students, 35 failed,2 remaining 85..."
  };

  for (const auto& s : test_strings) {
    I32Vector numbers = extract_numbers(s);
    std::cout << s << " => " << numbers << std::endl;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

which yields after compiling, e.g. with `clang++-13 -std=c++20 -o numbers numbers.cpp`:

> 120 brave students, 35 failed, remaining 85... => (120 35 85)
> 2PAC and U2 have class => ()

Comment: could you explain me what this `(R"(\b(\d+)[\.\,\:\;\!\?]*\b)")` means?

Comment: @RocketProcd This is the "regular expression." The usual proverb is: First I had a problem, then I decided to use regular expressions to solve it. Now I have 2 problems. ;) You will have to google for regular expressions. Giving a brief summary in a comment will not work.

Comment: I understand this part `[.\,\:\;\!\?]`

Comment: thanks, I'll try to figure out something

Comment: `R"()"` is the syntax for a c++ "verbatim string". Inside, you find the regexp itself. `\b` means "word boundary" and is probably redundant here, since we only deal with words. `(...)` is a capture group, also redundant, I guess. Only the digits. `\d+` means 1 or more decimal digits. The `[...]*` part means "followed by 0 or more punctuation characters. And then the final `\b` means word boundary again.

Comment: interesting part is that for this string `"120 brave students, 35 failed,2 remaining 85..."` function would throw `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stoi`

Comment: @RocketProcd Reload page and copy and paste the code again ;)

Comment: now it works :)

Comment: I posted an answer by myself, what do you think about it?